# Does "I've worked for Google" imply I still work for them?

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense

If I say "I've worked at Google" do you understand I still work at Google, I don't work anymore or you cant tell solely based on that sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By itself, "I've worked at Google," does not imply whether or not you still work there.  It is up to the inference of the listener, because you are leaving out the part that would clarify.  If you want to clarify, you can say, "I've worked at Google, and I still do," or "I've worked at Google in the past, but no longer."  Without some such explicit clarification, it remains unclear.

On the other hand, **if you specify a unit of time, you *are* implying** whether or not you still work there.

"I have worked at Google for four years," implies *you still work there*.

"I did work at Google for four years," implies *you no longer work there.*

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, present perfect tense indicates something you have finished in the past. So, "I've worked at Google" implies you have done the work at Google, but it does not tell whether you are now still working for google or not.